# How long will run powershell script to fetch old file names from the size of 3TB data?

Tags: powershell

I have developed one powershell script to find old files. Which is run perfectly to fetch file name from 900GB size of data around 120,000 files. But the same script has been running past 36hours in the size of 3TB data around 1.250,000 files.

I have mentioned the script below:

```
$fullPath = Read-Host "Please Enter File Location:"
$numdays = Read-Host "Please Enter No of days before files:"

function ShowOldFiles($path, $days)
{
    $files = @(get-childitem $path -include *.* -recurse | where {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days)) -and ($_.psIsContainer -eq $false)})
    if ($files -ne $NULL)
    {
        for ($idx = 0; $idx -lt $files.Length; $idx++)
        {
            $file = $files[$idx]
            Write-host $file.FullName
        }
    }
}

ShowOldFiles $fullPath $numdays

pause
```

I want to know howlong will it take to completed the process?

Please guide me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some adaptions:

Fist line in the function: 
You execute `(Get-Date).AddDays(-$days)` for every file you get. So, at 1.25 M files, you run it 1.25 M times. But you only need it once. This alone takes 83 Seconds on my Surface.

I dont see the point in the for-loop you created. If you wand to return the files, just do it, after you filtered them. You could pick the output up by running the function like `$output = ShowOldFiles...`. But then, you don't have an indicator, if the function is still running or not.

```
$fullPath = Read-Host "Please Enter File Location:"
$numdays = Read-Host "Please Enter No of days before files:"

function ShowOldFiles($path, $days)
{
    $refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days)
    get-childitem $path -include *.* -recurse | 
        Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt $refDate) -and ($_.psIsContainer -eq $false)} | 
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty Fullname
}

ShowOldFiles $fullPath $numdays

pause
```

If you want to know, how long it takes to finish this task, you need to know how much items you have to process. As we are talking about big numbers, I would not recomment the attempt to query all data only to make an programmatic estimation about the time to run the function. With the syntax I showed you, you should see the entrys as they apper - so you have an idicator that the code is still running. But like I said: It's not possible to estimate the time the process will take, without knowing how much items it needs to process